# Пилотный проект

Tags: омонимы, однокоренные-слова

Пилот - это то же самое, что и летчик, то есть, человек, занимающийся вождением самолета. Но одновременно пробный выпуск какого-то издания (не знаю о других областях) называют "пилотным проектом".
Какая тут связь? Или же это просто созвучные слова?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пилотный - пробный, экспериментальный.

"Pilot" по-английски не только существительное "пилот", но и прилагательное с таким значением.

Да и существительное "рilot" в английском языке имеет второе значение: кормчий, лоцман, то есть задающий путь.